# Html content get strange when WatiN.IE goes to a local file using GoTo method

Tags: watin

I want to test my С# parser using WatiN for navigation on site. Trying to get the html code of the page as follows.

```
var path = "C:\Coding\Projects\Crawler\TestData\akkanto\index.htm";
var browser = new IE();
browser.GoTo(path);
var htmlCode = browser.Html;
```

In the process of the code above the variable "htmlCode" is "`/r/n<BODY> </BODY>`".
Although the contents of the file index.html is

```
<html>
    <title>This is beautiful title.</title>
    <body>This is beautiful text.</body>
<html>
```

The browser displays the file correctly.
Why I'm not getting the real file content on variable htmlCode?
Framework 4.0 + Visaul Studio 2012 + WatiN-2.1.0.1196. 
Thanks in advice.

**UPD.**
Moreover, it is shown only for local files when you go to the link "http://google.com", it's fine.

Comment: Using your code and html, then doing a console.writeline, I get expected output of -> <BODY>This is beautiful text. </BODY>   Watin 2.1, Framework 3.5, run in IE9 / NUnit 2.5

Answer (score 0):

```
var path = "C:\Coding\Projects\Crawler\TestData\akkanto\index.htm";
Browser browser = new IE();
browser.GoTo(path);
var htmlCode = browser.Html;
Console.WriteLine(htmlCode);
```

Use Browser browser instead of var browser. The code is working fine on my machine having same configuration Framework 4.0 + Visaul Studio 2012 + WatiN-2.1.0.1196

Let me know if it is working fine.

Comment: I do not understand what is the difference, but your code does't work on my computer too.

Comment: IE inherits from Browser, and I'd bet isn't the issue Sergey is having. (From Watin.Core.IE.cs ->  public class IE : Browser)  Also, declaring a variable of one type and instantiting of another type is "smelly" to me -> Browser browser = new IE();

Comment: using System;
using WatiN.Core;

namespace Test
{
    class Program
    {
        [STAThread]
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var path = @"c:\tmp\index.htm";
            Browser browser = new IE();
            browser.GoTo(path);
            var htmlCode = browser.Html;
            Console.WriteLine(htmlCode);
        }
    }
}
Here is the complete code that I run. I definitely something wrong, because it is obvious that such a simple code should work correctly.

Comment: Maybe there are other ways to load the Html code from a local file in the watin browser?